# Is there any way to apply shader effect on particular cell of a Grid

Tags: wpf, shader, pixel-shader

Is there any way to apply shader effect on particular cell of a Grid.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply a shader effect on a particular Grid cell, but you can add a Rectangle or Border control within a panel (like Grid) to get the desired effect you are looking for.  Remember to add the Rectangle first, or play with ZIndex as I show below so that your code does not hide any controls.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="0" >
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle >
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" Margin="10" Text="Test 123" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    </Grid>
```